# How to clean up columns with values '10-12' (represented in range) in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-cleaning

I have Car Sales price dataset, where I am trying to predict the sales price given the features of a car. I have a variable called 'Fuel Economy city' which is having values like 10,12,10-12,13-14,.. in pandas dataframe. I need to convert this into numerical to apply regression algorithm. I don't have domain knowledge about automobiles. Please help.

I tried removing the hyphen, but it is treating as a four digit value which I don't think is correct in this context.

Comment: It's not clear whether you want help regarding the code or deciding what to do.
Why not start with a simple solution of taking the mean of the ranges? 10-12 -- > 11, 13-14 --> 13.5 etc...
This should keep them more or less in the same scale as the rest of the variables.

Answer (score 0):

You could try `pd.get_dummies()` which will make a separate column for the various ranges, marking each column True (1) or False (0). These can then be used in lieu of the ranges (which are considered categorical data.)

```
import pandas as pd

data = [[10,"blue", "Ford"], [12,"green", "Chevy"],["10-12","white", "Chrysler"],["13-14", "red", "Subaru"]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ["Fuel Economy city", "Color", "Make"])
print(df) 
df = pd.get_dummies(df)
print(df)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Fuel Economy city_10  Fuel Economy city_12  Fuel Economy city_10-12  \
0                     1                     0                        0   
1                     0                     1                        0   
2                     0                     0                        1   
3                     0                     0                        0   

Fuel Economy city_13-14  Color_blue  Color_green  Color_red  Color_white  \
0                        0           1            0          0            0   
1                        0           0            1          0            0   
2                        0           0            0          0            1   
3                        1           0            0          1            0   

Make_Chevy  Make_Chrysler  Make_Ford  Make_Subaru  
0           0              0          1            0  
1           1              0          0            0  
2           0              1          0            0  
3           0              0          0            1
```

Comment: I'm sorry but this is an odd way to go in my opinion. The values are clearly ordinal, why encode them into dummy labels and add more variables instead of just interpolating the ranges, especially when the ranges seem rather narrow?

Comment: You have a point, but interpolation (by definition) can mask data. For example; 12, 11-13, and 8-16 all average to 12, but say very different things. For mileage, it may (or may not) be immaterial. For other data (like manifold pressure) 12 and 8-16 are completely dissimilar. The decision is domain, and computation dependent. If different data ranges are so broad and frequent, that you end up with 100 columns and the computation starts choking - then sure, average. However, if it's not necessary, you get more precise value from the data.

Comment: However, if you also end up with mileage being (basically) unique for every row of data because of `get_dummies()` then interpolate. I would suggest posting an answer using interpolation, and let the OPer try both and see which gives more useful output.